# Datapump conversion from big endian to little endian

Tags: oracle, datapump

I have Oracle DataPump with tables in a single dump file. They were exported from the Big Endian system (Solaris), now I need to import them to Little Endian System (Windows).

If I try to import without the conversion I have unreadable cyrillyc symbols in my tables.

I have tried to use rman convert, but it seemed to be usabale only on datafiles which are used by Oracle, not the DataPumps.

I have no option to create a tablespace with the tables needed for transfer and to convert them.

How could be this solved?

Comment: I thought the datapump exports where endian-agnostic ?! Are you sure it's not a character set conversion problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems you are right and I have accidently choosen wrogn character set during database alter prior to import.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should use TTS instead, I though it looks like this is not fully supported.

look for example: How To Use Export And Import When Transferring Data Across Platforms Or Across 32-bit And 64-bit Servers (Doc ID 277650.1)

or

12C - Reduce Transportable Tablespace Downtime using Cross Platform Incremental Backup (Doc ID 2005729.1)